# Negative Look Behind alternative JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I'm trying to get my regex working.

Usually I can use a negative look behind to solve my issue, but javascript doesn't allow negative look behind.

I'm trying to match anything with Utility and Not Unit.

```
(Utility Type) //should match
(Utility Unit) //should not match
(util type) //should match
(utility) //should match
```

I've got `/^(.*util.*)(?<!unit)$/gi` working.. But like I mentioned, negative look behind doesn't work in javascript.  If you guys can think of another way to this, i'd appreciate the help.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you bother to search SO first? The question I linked to is the first match of **[javascript] negative lookbehind**

Comment: When it comes to negative look behinds, Oasis gave the best advice: don't do it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmpRLQZkTb8

Comment: Lookahead can work but would be a little slower ^(.*util(?:(?!unit$).)*)$

Comment: @sln That was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @caden311  - NP ..